# What is the purpose of passing the connection string name in my context class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am going through the [Creating an Entity Framework Data Model for an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) tutorial.  I ran into the same error others did:

"Unable to retrieve metadata for ProjectBuild"."Using the same DbCompiledModel to create contexts against different types of database servers is not supported. Instead, create a separate DbCompiledModel for each type of server being used."

I ran across this solution

"DbContext class was missing its default constructor defining the target CE database."

So I added the default constructor with this line of code:

```
 public SchoolContext()
        : base("SchoolContext"){}
```

My question is, what exactly are we doing here ?  Following a constructor with a colon does what ?  I am guessing we are telling SchoolContext that when we instantiate the DBContext use the constructor that takes a string ?  Is that correct ?

Thanks

Comment: `The :base syntax is a way for a derived type to chain to a constructor on the base class which accepts the specified argument. If omitted the compiler will silently attempt to bind to a base class constructor which accepts 0 arguments.`

Answer (score 0):

The DbContext ctor expects connection string or connection string name. By hardcoding the name of the connection string in the class derived from DbContext you make sure that regardless of where or how you run your application it will go to the config file and will read the connection string whose name you hardcoded in the constructor. This means that you can still configure your application (since you did not provide the connection string itself but its name) and at the same time the way to configure your app is well defined and won't "magically" change if you do some changes to your app.